# MapView not loading when going back to dialog (MapBox)

Tags: java, android, mapbox, android-mapview

Within a `fragment`, I create a dialog which contains a `MapView` (MapBox). This loads great and all. The dialog redirects the user (when the user clicks on a button) to another `Activity`. When the user presses back in that `Activity` (to go to the `dialog`), the `MapView` simply doesn't load anymore, until it gets pressed. I am using `MapBox's` implementation of the `MapView`.

I tried implementing the `onPause`, `onResume`, `onLowMemory` and `onDestroy` methods, by calling their respective methods in `MapView`, but that way the `MapView` does not load at all, not even when I click on it.

The fragment for an adapter:

```
public class DayAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

/**
 * Construct the fragment pager adapter.
 * @param fragmentManager The manager
 */
public DayAdapter(final FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

/**
 * Gets the Fragment to be rendered at <i>position</i>.
 * @param position The position of the item.
 * @return Fragment The Fragment that has to be rendered.
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new DayFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DayFragment.ARG_OBJECT, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Gets the total count of items.
 * @return Integer The amount of items.
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 100;
}

/**
 * Fragment to display the Day.
 */
public static class DayFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
    private final Client client = Client.getInstance();
    private WorkorderDialog d;

    /**
     * Constructs the Day view.
     * @param inflater The inflater for the Fragment.
     * @param container The container of the Fragment.
     * @param savedInstanceState The arguments of the saved state.
     * @return View The view of the day.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.day_fragment, container, false);
        final Bundle args = getArguments();
        final int dayPosition = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);
        final int deviation = dayPosition - 50;
        final Date devDate = DateUtil.getDateFromNow(deviation);
        final String renderedDate = DateUtil.getDayInWeek(devDate) + " "
                + DateUtil.getDayOfMonth(devDate) + " "
                + DateUtil.getMonth(devDate);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date)).setText(renderedDate);
        final String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(devDate);
        final JSONArray workOrders = client.getWorkOrders(currentDate);
        final ListView jobList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.jobList);
        jobList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                try {
                    d = new WorkorderDialog(client.getCurrentActivity(), workOrders.getJSONObject(i), renderedDate, savedInstanceState);
                    d.constructDialog();
                    d.show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("CrafterException", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        jobList.setEmptyView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.emptyTextView));
        jobList.setAdapter(new JobAdapter(workOrders, inflater));
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (d != null) {
            d.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (d != null) {
            d.onResume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (d != null) {
            d.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        if (d != null) {
            d.onLowMemory();
        }
    }
}
```

The Dialog:

```
public class WorkorderDialog extends Dialog {

private final JSONObject selectedOrder;
private final MapView googleMap;
private final Client client = Client.getInstance();
private final String renderedDate;
private final Bundle savedInstanceState;
private final Context context;

public WorkorderDialog(final @NonNull Context context, final JSONObject workorder, final String renderedDate, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super(context);
    setContentView(R.layout.workorder_dialog);
    this.context = context;
    this.selectedOrder = workorder;
    this.renderedDate = renderedDate;
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    this.googleMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.locationMap);
}

public void constructDialog() {
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    try {
        final String startTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm").format(new Date(selectedOrder.getLong("start_time") * 1000L));
        final String endTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm").format(new Date(selectedOrder.getLong("end_time") * 1000L));
        final String essentialInfo = renderedDate + " - " + startTime + " - " + endTime;
        final String title = selectedOrder.getJSONObject("client").getString("company");
        final String description = selectedOrder.getString("description");
        final String materials = JSONArrayUtil.sumProperty(selectedOrder.getJSONArray("materials"), "amount") + " materialen mee te nemen";
        final JSONObject address = selectedOrder.getJSONObject("location").getJSONObject("adress");
        final JSONObject contact = selectedOrder.getJSONObject("location").getJSONObject("contactperson");
        final String locationNotes = address.has("notes") ?
                ("".equals(address.getString("notes")) || "null".equals(address.getString("notes")) ?
                        "Geen locatie beschrijving" : address.getString("notes")) : "Geen locatie beschrijving";
        final String location = locationNotes + "\n" +
                address.getString("street") + " " +
                address.getString("number") + ", " +
                address.getString("city");
        final String contactPerson = contact.getString("first_name") + " " +
                contact.getString("last_name") + "\n" +
                contact.getString("phone");

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogTitle)).setText(title);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationText)).setText(location);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactText)).setText(contactPerson);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogInfo)).setText(essentialInfo);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText)).setText(description);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.materialsText)).setText(materials);
        (findViewById(R.id.closeDialogButton)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        if (!selectedOrder.has("localStatus") || (selectedOrder.has("localStatus") && selectedOrder.getInt("localStatus") != 3)) {
            (findViewById(R.id.openWorkOrder)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final Intent openWorkOrder = new Intent(client.getCurrentActivity(), WorkOrderActivity.class);
                    final Bundle passedArguments = new Bundle();
                    try {
                        if (!selectedOrder.has("localStatus")) {
                            selectedOrder.put("localStatus", 1);
                        }
                        WorkOrderHandler.getInstance().setEditingWorkOrder(selectedOrder);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("CrafterException", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    passedArguments.putString("workorder", selectedOrder.toString());
                    openWorkOrder.putExtras(passedArguments);
                    client.getCurrentActivity().startActivity(openWorkOrder);
                }
            });
        } else {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.openWorkOrder)).setImageResource(R.drawable.button_closed_workorder);
        }

        Mapbox.getInstance(getContext(), "pk.eyJ1IjoibWV0YWhleGFuZSIsImEiOiJjamFtYXE1Z3M0YmhoMndwN2lqZWp3aG91In0.VJrwxikM6yhPobgM59gl4g");

        googleMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!(address.get("lat") instanceof  String) && !(address.get("lng") instanceof String)) {
            final double lat = address.getDouble("lat");
            final double lng = address.getDouble("lng");

            googleMap.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
                    mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                            .icon(IconFactory.getInstance(getContext()).fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map)));
                    mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 11));
                    mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
                    mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setDoubleTapGesturesEnabled(false);
                    googleMap.onResume();
                }
            });
        }

        findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout10).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = null;
                try {
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=" + address.getString("street") + "+" + address.getString("number") + "+" + address.getString("city")));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("CrafterException", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("CrafterException", e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (googleMap != null) googleMap.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (googleMap != null) googleMap.onStop();
}

@Override
public void dismiss() {
    super.dismiss();
    if (googleMap != null) googleMap.onDestroy();
}

public void onResume() {
    if (googleMap != null) googleMap.onResume();
}

public void onPause() {
    if (googleMap != null) googleMap.onPause();
}

public void onLowMemory() {
    if (googleMap != null) googleMap.onLowMemory();
}
```

Comment: Can you supply your code of your fragment and the activity that you launch and return from as well as your manifest and XML files associated. Otherwise you are asking us to guess at a black-box problem

Comment: I updated my post!

Answer (score 1):

In a `Fragment` implementation of the `MapView` you need to call `MapView#onDestroy` in `Fragement#onDestroyView` like so:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
  super.onDestroyView();
  mapView.onDestroy();
}
```

This ensures the `MapView` is properly shutdown so it can be used again when you show the dialog a second time.  Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The thing is, the mapview is not in the `Fragment`. A class extending `Dialog` gets created in the `Fragment` and that class does not have an `onDestroyView`  method.

Comment: I think subclassing [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) rather than `Dialog` may help you here.